# tcpdf not picking up the border of div

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am using the `tcpdf` for generating the PDF file in one of my project and it is not picking up the border of div. But when I am using table in the same layout, then it is picking up the border.

Can u please suggest what I have to do for css in tcpdf?

Or any other way to include css file in tcpdf

```
<div class="div_info" style="width:100%; float:left; padding:10px 0px;">
    <div style="padding:2px 0 0 0; margin:0px; float:left;"><p>Interior/Exterior BPO</p>'.$row->interior_exterior_form.'</div>
    <div style="padding:2px 0 0 0; margin:0px; float:left;"><p>Property Address:</p>'.$row->property_address.'</div>
    <div style="padding:3px 0 0 33px; margin:0px; float:left;"><p>Borrower(s):</p>'.$row->borrowers.'</div>
    <div style="padding:3px 0 0 35px; margin:0px; float:left;"><p>Loan/REO#:</p>'.$row->loan_number.'</div>
</div>
```

Is it only supporting the inline css?

In the above layout, if I use the border, then it is not picking up that, but if I use the table then it add the border around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$html = <<<EOF
<style>   
    div.test {
        color: #CC0000;       
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #000;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<div class="test">This is your div content.</div>

<br />

EOF;

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

$pdf->lastPage();

$pdf->Output('sample.pdf', 'I');
```

For further details you may visit [this link](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php) and check example #61.